# Nginx X-Accell-Redirect gives 502 bad gateway

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails

I want to allow users to download files from a remote storage but I want to first auth the request through my rails app. I want to hand over the proxying of the remote file to nginx when rails has authenticated the request, to free up the ruby/rails thread.

I have this nginx conf file called proxy_download.conf:

```
   # Proxy download 
   location ~* ^/internal_redirect/(.*?)/(.*) {
     # Do not allow people to mess with this location directly
     # Only internal redirects are allowed
     internal;

     # Location-specific logging
     access_log logs/internal_redirect.access.log combined;
     error_log logs/internal_redirect.error.log warn;

     # Extract download url from the request
     set $download_uri $2;
     set $download_host $1;

     # Compose download url
     set $download_url http://$download_host/$download_uri;

     # Set download request headers
     proxy_set_header Host $download_host;
     proxy_set_header Authorization '';

     # The next two lines could be used if your storage 
     # backend does not support Content-Disposition 
     # headers used to specify file name browsers use 
     # when save content to the disk
     proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
     add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$args"';

     # Do not touch local disks when proxying 
     # content to clients
     proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

     # Download the file and send it to client
     proxy_pass $download_url;
   }
```

I import this into the main nginx conf like so:

```
include $ROOT/TO/APP/nginx.conf.d/proxy_download.conf;
```

The app deploys fine and runs properly with this setup.

These are the controller methods to start the download requeset:

```
  def x_accel_url(url, file_name = nil)
    uri = "/internal_redirect/#{url.gsub('http://', '').gsub('https://', '')}"
    uri << "?#{file_name}" if file_name
    return uri
  end

def download
    if auth_is_ok # do some auth logic here
        headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = x_accel_url('http://domain.com/file.ext')
        render :nothing => true
    end
end
```

When hitting this controller method through the browser, I get the famous nginx error:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

What's wrong with my setup? Thanks!